# Trying to use F# controllers with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#

I'm getting a "could not load type MyApp.Api.App from assembly MyApp.Api" runtime error in my c# mvc project that is referencing an f# web api library.  The c# project MyApp.Web has a project reference to the F# project MyApp.Api and has no compilation errors.  What could be the issue?

App.fs in the project MyApp.Api

```
namespace MyApp.Api

open System
open System.Web
open System.Web.Mvc
open System.Web.Routing
open System.Web.Http
open System.Data.Entity
open System.Net.Http.Headers

open System.Net.Http.Headers

type Route = { controller : string; action : string; id : UrlParameter }
type ApiRoute = { id : RouteParameter }

type App() =
    inherit System.Web.HttpApplication() 

    static member RegisterGlobalFilters (filters:GlobalFilterCollection) =
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute())

    static member RegisterRoutes(routes:RouteCollection) =
        routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" )
        routes.MapHttpRoute( "DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            { id = RouteParameter.Optional } ) |> ignore
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            { controller = "Home"; action = "Index"; id = UrlParameter.Optional } ) |> ignore

    member this.Start() =
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        App.RegisterRoutes RouteTable.Routes
        App.RegisterGlobalFilters GlobalFilters.Filters
```

And my global.asax.cs in MyApp.Web

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MyApp.Api;

namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class WebApiApplication :  MyApp.Api.App// System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            base.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you 'clean' your solution? You might even try closing VS, deleting the 'bin' and 'obj' folders within each of the project folders, then restarting VS and rebuilding the solution. It could be that the C# project builds OK because it's able to resolve the reference to `MyApp.Api.App` but then when the C# website runs, it's using an old (cached) version of the F# DLL where `MyApp.Api.App` doesn't exist (or has a different name/namespace).

Comment: tried cleaning, closing VS and deleting all the bin files and still having the same error...

Comment: Hmm... I do not see any immediate reason why this is failing. Could you possibly upload the project somewhere?

Comment: I'll try to upload something this weekend

Comment: Hmm I just created a new mvc web project and added the reference to the same f# project and it seems to work fine.  There must have been something in the original old mvc web project that was causing an issue but no compile time errors..

Answer (score 2):

You are registering your api route incorrectly. While the APIs look similar, they are not. You need to register your Web API route using the `HttpConfiguration` instance:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("", "", ...)
```

You are trying to map a Web API route into the MVC `RouteTable`. I'm actually surprised you don't get a compilation error.

---

So the above appears to not be the case. I must not have included an appropriate namespace when I tried before without pulling in Dan Mohl's project template.

You've subclassed your `MyApp.Api.App` type in `Global.asax.cs`. Dan's template doesn't include this. Instead, his template modifies the markup in `Global.asax` as follows:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="MyApp.Api.App" Language="C#" %>
<script Language="C#" RunAt="server">

  protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      base.Start();
  }

</script>
```

This seems to work just fine. I also got the following to work:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="MyApp.Web.WebApiApplication" Language="C#" %>
<!-- The following seems to be optional; just an extra, duplicate event handler.
     I was able to run the app with this script and without. -->
<script Language="C#" RunAt="server">

  protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      base.Start();
  }

</script>
```

Note that you need the full namespace, not just the type name. If that works correctly, then I think more of the code is necessary, as I can't find anything else that is wrong.

Comment: that's the code I copied from the default f# web api template.. which seems to work in the template..

Comment: Ah, I assumed you weren't using the template since you had a Global.asax.cs. However, you are right; the template appears to work fine.